# ActionListener not recognizing variables from main class

Tags: java, swing, variables, inheritance, actionlistener

I am trying to create a GUI payroll calculator for a Java class I am taking.  The requirements were that it must take the user inputs (one using a JComboBox), calculate the weekly pay and add the results to a JTable.  The user should be able to continue calculating for other employees and have an exit button.  I created the GUI in the main class and need two ActionListeners, one to exit and one to calculate and add to the JTable.

My problem is that when I start working on the calculate ActionListener, it is not recognizing the variables I set in the main class.  I have tried making them public, using the main class name DOT variable name (PayrollCalc.empName), initializing them and nothing seems to work. The code is not complete, as I have not even started to add to the JTable until I can get the actual calculations done first.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PayrollCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declare variables used
        String empName = null, entDept = null, calcdPay = null;
        String[] empDept = {"Marketing","IT","Accounting","Development","Payroll","Facilities"};
        String columnNames[] = {"Name","Department","Pay Check"};
        String dataValues [][] = {
                {empName,entDept,calcdPay}
        };

        double wrkHours = 0;
        double empRate = 0;
        double wklyPay = 0;

        //Create JTable and scrollPane for output
        JTable table;
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        table = new JTable (dataValues,columnNames);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Create JFrame object with title
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Employee Payroll Calculator");

        //Create combo box for department choices
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(empDept);
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField hourField = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField rateField = new JTextField(10);

        //Create JLables for input fields
        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel ("Name:");
        JLabel hourLbl = new JLabel ("Hours:");
        JLabel rateLbl = new JLabel ("Rate:");
        JLabel deptLbl = new JLabel ("Department:");

        //Create buttons for ActionListners
        JButton exitButton= new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new exitApp());
        exitButton.setSize(5,5);

        JButton calcButton= new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new calcApp());
        calcButton.setSize(5,5);

        //Create panels
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        panel1.add(nameLbl);
        panel1.add(nameField);
        panel1.add(deptLbl);
        panel1.add(combo);
        panel1.add(hourLbl);
        panel1.add(hourField);
        panel1.add(rateLbl);
        panel1.add(rateField);
        panel1.add(rateField);

        Panel panel2 = new Panel();
        panel2.add(calcButton);

        Panel panel3 = new Panel();
        panel3.add(calcButton);
        panel3.add(exitButton);

        Panel panel4 = new Panel();
        panel4.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        //creates the frame
        frame.setSize(950,200);
        frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel4);
        frame.setVisible(true);



    }
    //ActionListner for Exit button
    static class exitApp implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    //ActionListner for Calculate button
    static class calcApp implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c)
        {
            empName = nameField.getText();
            entDept = combo.getName();
            wrkHours = Double.parseDouble(hourField.getText());
            empRate = Double.parseDouble(rateField.getText());
            wklyPay = wrkHours * empRate;
            calcdPay = new Double(wklyPay).toString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't set variables in a main **class**. You've got local variables in a main **method**.

Comment: Bump those variables outside of that method and set the level of access (private, public, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Since the variables you're trying to access in your `ActionListener` are ***local*** to your `main()` they are not *visible* to your *static* class. Also, initializing your GUI inside the *static main()* is forcing the use of *statics* every where which as you can tell from the comments below is a bad practice.

So, move the initialization out to a *constructor* and the local variables as *instance* level member fields. Along with this you would need to switch from *static nested* classes to using *inner* classes instead.

*Instance* members of your class would then be available to your *inner* `ActionListener` classes.

```
public class PayrollCalc {

    //Declare variables used
    private String empName = null, entDept = null, calcdPay = null;

    private double wrkHours = 0;
    private double empRate = 0;
    private double wklyPay = 0;

    private JComboBox combo;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField hourField;
    private JTextField rateField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PayrollCalc();
    }

    public PayrollCalc() {
        // ...
        combo = new JComboBox(empDept);
        nameField = new JTextField(15);
        hourField = new JTextField(10);
        rateField = new JTextField(10);
        // ...
    }

    // non-static ActionListener inner classes
}
```

Comment: *"Move them out as class level static member fields."*  The `static` part is a bad move and bad advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson OP was initializing everything in static main and the listeners were static too. Hence, I suggested the quick fix. Working on the answer again. Please check back in five.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Please, care to have another look at my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MonadNewb: Please, care to have another look at my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal  Care to have an up-vote.  :)  (<-  OK - as a sentence that makes no sense at all, but I guess you can figure my meaning..)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I am understanding.  If I am getting this, I should create a class that will construct the calculator window and both action listeners.  Then I initialize the calculator in the main class?

Comment: @MonadNewb Thank you for reviewing my answer.

Comment: @user2554353 Yes, you've understood correctly. You can update your question with your final approach and we'll be happy to take a look again.

Comment: Thank you, I am working on it now.  altering my code is not as easy as i thought...

Answer (score 2):

Look , every variable has its Scope ... and you have not defined anything as a member class variable so nothing will act as a global variable .

`you have defined variable inside main method () so their scope is limited to only main method` thats the reason behind your problem .

Comment: Thanks Tushar, I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Accept it as your Answer !